# Select random bin from a set in Aerospike Query Language?

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

I want to select a sample of random 'n' bins from a set in the namespace. Is there a way to achieve this in Aerospike Query Language?

In Oracle, we achieve something similar with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table-name> sample block(10) where rownum < 101
```

The above query fetches blocks of size of 10 rows from a sample size of 100.

Can we do something similar to this in Aerospike also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows are like records in Aerospike, and columns are like bins. You don’t have a way to sample random columns from a table, do you?

You can sample random *records* from a set using `ScanPolicy.maxRecords` added to a scan of that set. Note the new (optional) [set indexes](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/set-indexes.html) in Aerospike version 5.6 may accelerate that operation.

Each namespace has its [data partitioned](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-distribution.html) into 4096 logical partitions, and the records in the namespace evenly distributed to each of those using the characteristics of the 20-byte RIPEMD-160 digest. Therefore, Aerospike doesn't have a `rownum`, but you can leverage the data distribution to sample data.

Each partition is roughly 0.0244% of the namespace. That's a sample space you can use, similar to the SQL query above. Next, if you are using the [`ScanParition`](https://docs.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#scanPartitions-com.aerospike.client.policy.ScanPolicy-com.aerospike.client.query.PartitionFilter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.aerospike.client.ScanCallback-java.lang.String...-) method of the client, you can give it the [`ScanPolicy.maxRecords`](https://docs.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/ScanPolicy.html#maxRecords) to pick a specific number of records out of that partition. Further you can start after an arbitrary digest (see  [`PartitionFilter.after`](https://docs.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PartitionFilter.html#after-com.aerospike.client.Key-)) if you'd like.

Ok, now let's talk data browsing. Instead of using the aql tool, you could be using the [Aerospike JDBC driver](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc), which works with any JDBC compatible data browser like DBeaver, SQuirreL, and Tableau. When you use `LIMIT` on a [`SELECT`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc/blob/main/docs/examples.md#select) statement it will basically do what I described above - use partition scanning and a max-records sample on that scan. I suggest you try this as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

AQL is a tool written using Aerospike C Client. Aerospike does not have a SQL like query language *per se* that the server understands. What ever functionality that AQL provides is documented - type HELP on the **aql>** prompt.

You can write an application in C or Java to achieve this. For example, in Java, you can do a scanAll() API call with maxRecords defined in the ScanPolicy. I don't see AQL tool offering that option for scans. (It just allows you to specify a scan rate, one of the other ScanPolicy options.)